# How do I transfer data from one oracle database to another oracle database with airflow

Tags: oracle, airflow

i'm trying to transfer data from one oracle_db1.table1 to another oracle_db2.table1.  I've already installed the backport-provider: https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-oracle/.
Import works fine now. But trying first tasks i get this error. I think it's something about the connection:

Here the **error log**

```
[2020-08-18 12:30:15,485] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO -
[2020-08-18 12:30:15,485] {base_hook.py:84}
INFO - Using connection to: id: DB1234.
Host: 192.168.50.123:1521/testserver, Port: 1521, Schema: blup, Login: blup, Password: xxXXX, extra: None
[2020-08-18 12:30:15,485] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO -
[2020-08-18 12:30:15,485] {connection.py:342} ERROR - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).
```

And here is my example **DAG Task**:

```
T3 = OracleToOracleOperator(
        task_id="insert_data_to_db",
        oracle_destination_conn_id= "BCDEFG",
        destination_table= "BCDEFG.TEST_BENUTZER3",
        oracle_source_conn_id= "DESTINATION_DB",
        source_sql= """
        SELECT * FROM DESTINATION_DB.BENUTZER
        """,
        source_sql_params=None,
        rows_chunk=5000
    )
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you show me your connection object ? How are you adding that ? Also check if your connectivity is good from your airflow instance.

Comment: Hello, the problem is solved. It was a problem with the connection. There were inputs in "extra". I deleted them. now it works. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

problem with the connection. There were inputs in "extra". I deleted them. then it works